# 3ds Max SDK How to set tranformation matrix for pivot only

Tags: c++, plugins, 3dsmax

i'm trying to create my import plugin for 3ds max and i stuck with problem. How to assign transformation matrix to pivot only.

I tried to use SetNodeTM, but it transforms pivot with object itself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any methods that directly operate on the object's pivot *transform*, but `INode` does provide methods to get/set the pivot position, rotation and scale. So if you are able to decompose your pivots into those components, you can set it that way.

From the SDK:

```
/*! \remarks Sets the position portion of the object offset from
the node. See the Advanced Topics section on
~{ Transformation and Rotation }~ for an overview of the object offset transformation.
\param p Specifies the position portion of the object-offset. */
virtual void    SetObjOffsetPos(Point3 p)=0;

/*! \remarks Sets the rotation portion of the object-offset from
the node. See the Advanced Topics section on
~{ Transformation and Rotation }~ for an overview of the object offset transformation.
\param q The rotation offset. */
virtual void    SetObjOffsetRot(Quat q)=0;

/*! \remarks Sets the scale portion of the object-offset matrix.
See the Advanced Topics section on
~{ Transformation and Rotation }~ for an overview of the object offset transformation.
\param sv The scale portion of the offset. See Class ScaleValue. */
virtual void    SetObjOffsetScale(ScaleValue sv)=0;
```